# How to find the longest common ENDING between 2 strings in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to find code that will allow to find a common ending between two strings, for example:

```
s1 = 'running'

s2 = 'ruminating'
```

and the output would result in:

```
'ing'
```

---

It must be specifically for the ending of the string but i am not sure how to do this

Answer (score 1):

The stdlib already has [`commonprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix):

```
>>> strings = ['running', 'ruminating']
>>> from os.path import commonprefix
>>> commonprefix(strings)
'ru'
```

It's easily adapted for your needs:

```
>>> commonprefix([s[::-1] for s in strings])[::-1]
'ing'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function and iterate:

```
s1 = 'running'
s2 = 'ruminating'

def get_common(s1, s2):
    L = []
    for i, j in zip(s1[::-1], s2[::-1]):
        if i != j:
            break
        L.append(i)
    return ''.join(L[::-1])

common = get_common(s1, s2)  # ing
```